# highslide gallery

Tags: javascript, highslide

I'm using Highslide to show my photos. I want to introduce simple gallery - if somebody click photo "dolno.jpg" it will show up gallery with 3 photos. Now is only one (1.jpg). I have 3 pictures:
1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg
How can I do this? This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/highslide/highslide.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/highslide/highslide.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    // override Highslide settings here
    // instead of editing the highslide.js file
    hs.graphicsDir = '/highslide/graphics/';
</script>

<td>
<a class="highslide" href="1.jpg" onclick="return hs.expand(this, { captionText: '<b>THIS</b>' } )">
<img src="/logafirm/dolno.jpg" id="imgg" title="Click to enlarge" height="80" weight="80"></a>
 <font color="#52180"><b>THIS</font></b></A>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just duplicate the anchor element for every other image you want to display.

Like this

```
<a class="highslide" href="1.jpg" onclick="return hs.expand(this, { captionText:    '<b>THIS</b>' } )">
  <img src="/logafirm/dolno.jpg" id="imgg" title="Click to enlarge" height="80" weight="80">
</a>
<a class="highslide" href="2.jpg" onclick="return hs.expand(this, { captionText: '<b>THE OTHER IMAGE</b>' } )">
  <img src="/logafirm/THE_OTHER_IMAGE.jpg" id="imgg" title="Click to enlarge" height="80" weight="80">
</a>
```

ALso you will need specify your slideshow settings..

According to the docs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
hs.addSlideshow({
// slideshowGroup: 'group1',
interval: 5000,
repeat: false,
useControls: true,
fixedControls: true,
overlayOptions: {
    opacity: .6,
    position: 'top center',
    hideOnMouseOut: true
}
});

// Optional: a crossfade transition looks good with the slideshow
hs.transitions = ['expand', 'crossfade'];
</script>
```

And lastly..If you want only display first thumbnail, simply hide the others..With CSS or maybe better with javascript (user without js will see the images)

Answer (score 0):

Highslide has a built-in mechanism to do what you want - no need to fiddle with CSS or Javascript to hide the other two thumbnails.

http://www.highslide.com/examples/mini-gallery.html